# Disable button on unchecked box not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm having trouble disabling the submit button when the checkbox is unchecked. It works for everything else except the checkbox.

```
<fieldset>
    <input class="disableButton" id="card" type="text" />
    <select class="selected-state disableButton" id="month" >
        <option value="">Exp. Month</option>
        <option value="01">01 - Jan</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <select class="selected-state disableButton" id="year" />
        <option value="">Exp. Year</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <input class="disableButton" id="cvc" type="text" />
        <p>I agree to the <a href="http://nofusstoothbrush.com/terms-conditions/" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a> <input id="termsCheck" type="checkbox" checked></p>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input id="submitCard" class="action-button" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" title="Please fill all required fields" />
</fieldset>    

$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.disableButton').on('keyup change', function(){
                if ($('#card').val().length < 10 || $('#cvc').val().length < 3 || $('#month').val() == '' || $('#year').val() == '' || $('#termsCheck').attr('checked') == false){
                        $('#submitCard').prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                        $('#submitCard').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: use `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: I have changed it to `prop` but doesn't work dynamically. It works once, but clicking it a second time does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.is(':checked')` or `.prop('checked')` to assess the checkbox status:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.disableButton').on('keyup change', function(){
        if ($('#card').val().length < 10 || $('#cvc').val().length < 3 || $('#month').val() == '' || $('#year').val() == '' || !$('#termsCheck').is(':checked')){
                $('#submitCard').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
                $('#submitCard').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/m9KN4/

You also need to add the class `disabledButton` to the checkbox element, and as a rule of thumb, it should be the user who has to give consent explicitly, so it's better to **leave it unchecked first**:

```
<input id="termsCheck" type="checkbox" class="disableButton" />
```

p/s: I think you have accidentally made one of the `<select>` element a self-closing one...

Comment: Thank you - it disables the button when unchecking the box now, but does not enable it when checking it again... and thanks for the heads up on the `select`

Comment: @ProfessorB You will to add the class `disableButton` to the checkbox element. And I strongly recommend removing the default checked state of giving consent, because users have to give explicit consent... so updated Fiddle and answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  <input class="disableButton" id="card" type="text" />
  <select class="selected-state disableButton" id="month" >
    <option value="">Exp. Month</option>
    <option value="01">01 - Jan</option>
    ...
  </select>
  <select class="selected-state disableButton" id="year" />
    <option value="">Exp. Year</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    ...
  </select>
  <input class="disableButton" id="cvc" type="text" />
    <p>I agree to the <a href="http://nofusstoothbrush.com/terms-conditions/" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a> <input id="termsCheck" type="checkbox" checked></p>
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <input id="submitCard" class="action-button" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" title="Please fill all required fields" />
</form>    


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').on('keyup change', function(){
    if ($('#card').val().length < 10 || $('#cvc').val().length < 3 || $('#month').val() == '' || $('#year').val() == '' || $('#termsCheck').prop('checked') == false){
      $('#submitCard').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#submitCard').prop('disabled', '');
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/622WM/1/

Comment: It looks like this only disables or enables the button once without going back to the previous state when clicking again

Comment: Why? it checks the condition every form keyup or change. Try the code, it works.

Comment: I'm trying your jsfiddle example and it's not working

Comment: Make sure you fill out all the field according to the conditions set in the `if()` statement.

Comment: You shouldn't use `.removeProp()` — from your fiddle you can see that once the button is enabled, it cannot be disabled anymore in the future despite not meeting the if conditions. From [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/): Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. **This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element.** Use `.prop()` to set these properties to false instead.

Comment: Interesting. Ok thanks I'm updating the answer. In FF it does work btw. +1